# Creating a NULL object type within template class definition

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++14

For a template class

```
template<typename T>
class node{

public:
static auto null_node_type = typename //shared pointer holding node<T>*
                                // cast from NULL

};
```

I would like to include a type declaration as above within the template definition, but not sure how to achieve this.

I tried the following, which didn't work:

```
    1. static auto null_node_type = 
typename shared_ptr<reinterpret_cast<node<T>*>(NULL)>;
```

In this case, the compiler complains that the `shared_ptr<>` template expects a type.

```
2. std::function<shared_ptr<T>(T)> make_null_obj_type = [] (T arg){

       return(make_shared<arg>(NULL));

};

template<typename T>
class node{

public:

static auto null_node_type = make_null_obj_type<node<T>>;

};
```

In this case, the compiler flags the error that `node<T>` (wherein `T` is substituted by the actual template argument) is not a complete object type.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: `typename shared_ptr<reinterpret_cast<node<T>*>` ... why do you think you need `typename` or `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: @Praetorian reinterpret_cast() to cast a NULL to the required pointer type.

Comment: Not required, see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL). And what about the `typename`? Or `std::function<shared_ptr<T>(T)>` in the second version? How's that related to a `shared_ptr<node<T>>`? You seem to be randomly trying various things in the hope one would compile. If you had a non-template class, how would define a `static int` member (you probably want it to be `const`)? Start with that and work your way forward.

Comment: @Praetorian I declared the type as static const shared_ptr<node<T>> null_sp2node within the template definition and defined the variable outside the template definition. That seems to work.